# Cannot debug.traceTransaction in geth: "missing trie node"

Tags: go-ethereum

I can trace only transactions that where executed in the last 2 - 3 hours with my geth, I get the following errors on transactions executed for 5 hours and more:

```
> debug.traceTransaction('0x5c504ed432cb51138bcf09aa5e8a410dd4a1e204ef84bfed1be16dfba1b22060');
    Error: missing trie node 
    691fc4f4d21d10787902e8f3266711f1d640e75fedbeb406dc0b8d3096128436 (path )
        at web3.js:3143:20
        at web3.js:6347:15
        at web3.js:5081:36
        at <anonymous>:1:1

> debug.traceTransaction('0x19f1df2c7ee6b464720ad28e903aeda1a5ad8780afc22f0b960827bd4fcf656d');
Error: missing trie node 5412c03b1c22d01fe37fc92d721ab617f94699f9d59a6e68479145412af3edae (path )
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Geth node is fullу synced:

```
> eth.syncing
false
```

I run it with the following command:

```
geth --port XXX --datadir XXX --rpcport XXX --rpc --rpcapi admin,debug,miner,shh,txpool,personal,eth,net,web3 console
```

I have tried both geth versions `1.7.0` and `1.7.2`. Deleting the blockchain database and resyncing does not help.

How to cope with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geth uses fast sync by default. Use `--syncmode=full` for full sync. The full database size is over 200Gb for now.

---

The answer was found here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15088

The reason is described here: https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/